# Use event in multiple different components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a JscrollPane which holds a JPanel on which I draw. I would like to use the MouseWheelEvent to:

- zoom the (with CTRL+Wheel) Panel content
- and to scroll the scrollpane (with just the wheel)

Each action by itself works, but I dont't manage to make both work. As soon as I add a MouseWheelListener to the JPanel, the event does not arrive at the JScrollPanels listner.

How can I get the MouseWheelEvent to be forwarded the JScrollPanes MouseWheelListener if it has not been used in the JPanel?

EDIT: Thanks for the hint: Is there also a way to make both listeners listen? Because the scrolling in the scrollpane is actually default implemented. So is there a way to use it without any additional implementation?

Thanks & Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your custom listener dispatch the events (which it doesn't want to handle itself) to the sender's parent, eventually, the scrollPane will pick them up:

```
    final MouseWheelListener wheel = new MouseWheelListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            if (shouldHandleHere(e)) {
                LOG.info("do-my-own-stuff");
            } else {
                LOG.info("dispatch-to-parent");
                e.getComponent().getParent().dispatchEvent(e);
            } 
        }

        public boolean shouldHandleHere(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            return (e.getModifiersEx() & MouseWheelEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) != 0;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

When you register a listener, you assign a method to execute when a particular behaviour is detected. Suppose I have :

- Listener1 executing method1
- Listener2 executing method2

If listener1 prevent the listener2 from listening, you just have to call method1 and method2 when listener1 is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there also a way to make both listeners listen? See Edit.