# Continue MouseWheelEvent propagation if not handled manually

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a component inside a `JScrollPane`, and I would like to handle some scroll events. However, I don't want to handle all of them. Unfortunately, when I add a `MouseWheelListener` to my child component, the scroll stops receiving the scrolling events.

How can I “pass on” events that I don't want to handle manually?

Comment: Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379504/use-event-in-multiple-different-components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about?

```
Component.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent e);
```

Basically you would need to call:

```
getParent().dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
```

Now you might need to dig out the scrollPane, but you can play around with the idea

Comment: I was hoping that there was a way to continue normal event propagation, but I guess this is the best possible solution.

Comment: The problem is that the mouse events only occur on the first, top level component interested in those events.  You could attach a pre/post awt event handler, however, this is overkill for what you want to achieve